# How to extract parts of an address from a string?

Tags: javascript

How to get address, city, state, country, pin code from the below strings:

```
var str1 = "69, 2nd Floor, J.P. & Devi Jambukeshwar Arcade, Miller’s Road,Bengaluru, Karnataka 560052, India"; 

var str2 = "Shivaji Nagar,Bengaluru, Karnataka, India";
```

Comment: you should use some geo coding API's

Answer (score 0):

Without key `(key:value)` We can't get exact value. We can split the string,  Make array and use. In array we have value with index and get value by index. But you must use `key:value` pair for dynamic data. Below example is not solution, some other scenario you can use like this.

```js
var app = angular.module('exApp',[]);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
var str1 = "69, 2nd Floor, J.P. & Devi Jambukeshwar Arcade, Miller’s Road,Bengaluru, Karnataka 560052, India";
$scope.str1 = str1.split(','); //console.log($scope.str1);
var str2 = "Shivaji Nagar,Bengaluru, Karnataka, India";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="exApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
<div ng-repeat="str in str1 track by $index">{{str}}</div><br>{{str1}} <br><br> {{str1[0]}}, {{str1[1]}}, {{str1[2]}}, {{str1[3]}}, {{str1[4]}}, {{str1[5]}}, {{str1[6]}}
</body>
```

Comment: My requirement is to show these value in a modal.I am not getting address as key and value. It is a string.I need to populate city,state,pincode,country in a modal.

Comment: You should ask your API team  to give JSON or XML